# Finding files using /\.c/

Tags: regular-expression, ls, wildcards

I was wondering if there is a way to find files that end with `.c` using `/\.c/`. How would I do that?

I have tried `ls -l /\.c/` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does `using /.c/` mean to you?

Comment: i dont know either. my professor said we can find files that end with anything for example .c using this command '/\.c/' but I don't know how to use it @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

Comment: All shells allow `glob` patterns, like `*.c`, to find such files. So `ls -l *.c` should do what you want. `/\.c/` looks like a search expression used by an editor like `vi`.

Comment: Thanks it works now @NickD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:
`find . -name '*.c'`
or with more details on the found files:
`find . -name '*.c' -ls`

Comment: Seems awfully complicated for `ls *.c`

Comment: I assumed @Beakal Begashaw wants to find all files with .c extension, including in the sub-directories of the search path. If he wants to find the .c files _only_ in in the current directory, indeed, your answer is more concise.